# errorMessages:schema is not editable

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise

I am using DataStax Enterprise 5.1.5 on Linux Platform and created a test schema on `Cassandra DB`. Created a search index integrated with Solr and now trying to edit the `Solr` schema file(`schema.xml`) using [Solr Rest API](http://host:port/solr/keyspace.table/schema):

While editing schema file I am facing following error

> errorMessages: schema is not editable

Need some suggestion on this. Found some clues while searching but no help yet.
Thanks,
Divya Garg

Answer (score 1):

You need to make all changes in core/schema using the `dsetool`, because DSE manages all cores.

You need to do 2 steps before:

1. Get core configuration with `dsetool get_core_config keyspace.table > solrconfig.xml`
2. Get schema with `dsetool get_core_schema keyspace.table > schema.xml`

Then make changes to any of these files & recreate a core:

1. Unload core with `dsetool unload_core keyspace.table`
2. Create core with `dsetool create_core keyspace.table schema=schema.xml solrconfig=solrconfig.xml` (add `reindex=true` if you want to load existing data from table)

Answer (score 0):

As of DSE 5.1, you can also alter and reload the schema for your search index directly from CQL. (See https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/search/indexMgmt.html)